# How to get current value of header cell? (incl. nested headers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handsontable

I have a handsontable, where some of the headers are checkboxes, and some of them are select boxes.

How do you access the header to check the value of a select/checkbox inside the header cell?

JSFiddle (with nested headers - same as my project): http://jsfiddle.net/Lmh50uwu/

I'd like to access the value of `mybox` and `myselect`

`$("#mybox")` or`$("#myselect")` don't work.

I'd like to be able to check the value of `myselect` and `mybox` at any point after the DOM load.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var example1 = document.getElementById('example1');
  
  var hot = new Handsontable(example1, {
    data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(5,10),
    colHeaders: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    nestedHeaders: [
      ['<input type="checkbox" id="mybox">', {label: 'B', colspan: 8}, 'C'],
      ['<select id="myselect" name="menu" class="selectpicker"><option value="LVW">LVW</option><option value="SIM">SIM</option></select>', {label: 'E', colspan: 4}, {label: 'F', colspan: 4}, 'G'],
      ['H', {label: 'I', colspan: 2}, {label: 'J', colspan: 2}, {label: 'K', colspan: 2}, {label: 'L', colspan: 2}, 'M'],
      ['N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W']
    ]
  });
  
  
});

$("#mybox").remove();

console.log("test")
var elem = document.getElementById("myselect");
// console.log(elem.value); // elem is null here
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.0.0/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.0.0/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
<div>
  <div id="example1" class="hot handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: updated: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmh50uwu/2/

EDIT: added the snippet into my post, but can't test because my company blocks access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that custom HTML elements in row & column headers need to be identified by class name, not by id. **This is because row and column headers are duplicated in the DOM tree and id attribute must be unique.**

(See this link: http://bollwyvl.github.io/jquery-handsontable/demo/renderers_html.html)

**Solution:**

use `<input type="checkbox" class="mybox">` together with getter `$(".mybox")[1].checked`

instead of

use `<input type="checkbox" id="mybox">` together with getter `$("#mybox").checked`